# Tensorflow model prediction resulting in memory leak (Out of Memory)

Tags: tensorflow, image-processing, keras, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to run predictions for a image classification model on large(800000) number of image files. Below is a code snippet of how my data pipeline looks like:

```
import tensorflow as tf
BATCH_SIZE = 128

def configure_for_performance(ds):
    ds = ds.batch(BATCH_SIZE)
    ds = ds.prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
    tf.keras.backend.clear_session()
    return ds


def decode_img(img):
    img = tf.io.decode_jpeg(img, channels=3)
    img = tf.image.resize(img, [IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH])
    return img


def process_path(file_path):
    img = tf.io.read_file(file_path)
    img = decode_img(img)
    return img

list_ds = tf.data.Dataset.list_files([filepath1,filepath2,...,filepathN],
                                     shuffle=False)

files_list = list()
for files in list_ds.as_numpy_iterator():
    files_list.append(files.decode("utf-8"))

test_ds = list_ds.map(process_path, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
test_size = test_ds.cardinality().numpy()
test_ds = configure_for_performance(test_ds)
test_ds = test_ds.map(
    lambda images: normalization_sequential_layer(images))

test_steps = test_size // BATCH_SIZE + 1
score = tf.nn.softmax(model.predict(test_ds, steps=test_steps))
```

I am running it on a machine with 32 cores and 64 GB RAM(No GPU) but the process runs for quite some time and then exits with the message `+Killed` which on research I could relate to out of RAM issue(memory leak happening over time and after one point it goes out of RAM). On further research, I can see people facing OOM issues when having a for loop around the model.predict , not sure what could be the reason here.